# jquery multiple conditions on selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the below jquery snippet which filters for any links which has a specific extension mentioned in the regular expression. To this condition, I want to check if the href value starts with `http://www.xyz.com` . How can that be done?

```
$('a:regex(href,\\.(zip|mp\\d+|mpe*g|pdf|docx*|pptx*|xlsx*|jpe*g|png|gif|tiff*))$').live('click', function (e) {
    // do some action..
});
```

The regex helper function is below

```
jQuery.expr[':'].regex = function (elem, index, match) {
    var matchParams = match[3].split(','),
        validLabels = /^(data|css):/,
        attr = {
            method: matchParams[0].match(validLabels) ?
                        matchParams[0].split(':')[0] : 'attr',
            property: matchParams.shift().replace(validLabels, '')
        },
        regexFlags = 'ig',
        regex = new RegExp(matchParams.join('').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''), regexFlags);
    return regex.test(jQuery(elem)[attr.method](attr.property));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like there's an error in the regex (with the position of the `$`).  But here's how you would chain the selectors:

```
$('a[href^=http://www.xyz.com]:regex(href,\\.(zip|mp\\d+|mpe*g|pdf|docx*|pptx*|xlsx*|jpe*g|png|gif|tiff*)$)').live('click', function (e) {
    // do some action..
});
```

Comment: @Rohler: Great! It worked. Thanks. The Regex is from the free gaAddOns script, I've tested it and seems to work fine.